# How to change the Go AWS SDK default download directory in Linux. Getting no space left on device error

Tags: linux, go, aws-sdk-go

I am trying to download the Go AWS SDK but I don't have much space in my root.
I have mounted another device (**/mnt/device2/**) where I have 15 GB space available.

When I run the command `go get -u github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/...` I get the error

> go build github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/macie2: mkdir
> /tmp/go-build3967698646/b570/: no space left on device

I want to change the default download directory from `/tmp/` to `/mnt/device2/`.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Have you tried `TMPDIR=/mnt/device2 go get -u github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/...`?

Comment: Haven't tried it yet. I tried to search `TMPDIR` using `printenv` but couldn't fine it. Where is this environment variable located ??

Comment: It's an environment variable defined by Posix. It doesn't have to be set. If unset, most programs default to /tmp, [Go included](https://pkg.go.dev/os#TempDir).

Comment: @Peter I tried `TMPDIR=/mnt/device2 go get -u github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/...` and I didn't get `no space left on device` error. But I also couldn't find the `aws/aws-sdk-go` directory either.

Answer (score 1):

Going by the documentation [here](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go/internal/get)

> When checking out a new package, get creates the target directory
> GOPATH/src/. If the GOPATH contains multiple entries, get
> uses the first one. For more details see: 'go help gopath'.

Further it describes each flag and none of them seem to allow you to change the download directory.

It kinda makes sense in that it removes complexity and the fact that if you're using modules primarily - changing `GOPATH` should be pretty seemless.

My suggestion, provided you're using go modules, would be to just change your `GOPATH` env variable to point to your newly mounted storage device. This will:

1. Re-Download all your dependencies in all your golang projects when you build or `go mod tidy` them
2. If you use remote tools and used this server as you dev env - you would need to run `go mod tidy` for each project to prevent code editors and IDEs from screaming error at you.
3. If you choose to delete the old `GOPATH` directory - make sure your new `GOPATH/bin` is in `PATH` - and you would need to re-install any binaries you may have installed there.

Comment: Thanks @Kelsnare, I did change the GOPATH env variable to point to `/mnt/device2` but download is still pointing to `/tmp` directory.